# Delphi 7 keeps using old outdated form

Tags: delphi, forms

Changed, updated, form is not used even though uses and project settings seem fine, old form files removed from disk.

Is this a bug in the IDE? I may just delete the form and copy it into another unit with a new name.

Answer (score 1):

If it's using an old form it has to be getting it from somewhere--it doesn't appear out of thin air.  Two scenarios come to mind:

1)  It's somewhere where you don't realize.  Search your system for files by that name.

2)  Unless you do a build Delphi compiles based on timestamps.  If the clock was wrong when it was compiled before the .dcu can have a more recent time and thus it gets skipped in compiling.  I've hit this more than once with timezones.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to find it is to first move the project to a different new folder and try to compile it. This should produce and error that will help you to find the culprit. If this does not work then it is settings like paths etc in your libraries that are at fault.

Also make sure that you deleted all ".dcu" files in the project before re-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a bug in the IDE.

You are referencing that form in some setting in your project or environment, which you didn't find yet and which takes precedence to options you already tweaked.

Where do you need to go to resolve your problem? Well, that's difficult to say without looking at your development environment and your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before.  It is always something referenced that I wasn't aware of.

You can do a grep for something from the form and see where it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. The first one I tried, moving the files, mm2010, showed it was my code that was at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Although the form/unit is not included in the project file (dpr), it is still referenced by some other unit. So the compiler links the res into the application. Look for the unit name you want to remove in other units' uses clauses.